# Accessing values from different levels of a nested object within the same append instance using D3.js

Tags: d3.js, nested

What is the best way to use values from two different levels of nesting in the same append instance?

This is the data I have:

```
data = [   
    {"key":"comp1","values":[
        {"id": 0,"x":10,"y": 20},
        {"id": 1,"x":20,"y": 10},
        {"id": 2,"x":30,"y": 70},
        {"id": 3,"x":40,"y": 80}  
       ]},    
    {"key":"comp2","values":[
        {"id": 0,"x":10,"y": 80},
        {"id": 1,"x":20,"y": 60},
        {"id": 2,"x":30,"y": 10},
        {"id": 3,"x":40,"y": 40}   
       ]} 
       ]
```

I would like to display the key as text, but using the x and y values from the last item (id:3).

This is my thinking so far:

```
.append("text")
   .data(data)   
   .text(function(d) { return d.key; }) // so far so good
   .data(d.values) // trying to get one level in the nest
        .attr("x", 100 )
        .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
```

Any suggestions to help me in my thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the d.values because its part of the binded data

with your example:

```
.append("text")
   .data(data)
    .text(function(d) { return d.key; }) // so far so good
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.values[d.values.length - 1].x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.values[d.values.length - 1].y); })
    .attr("dy", ".35em");
```

```js
const svg = d3.select('svg');

const data = [   
    {"key":"comp1","values":[
        {"id": 0,"x":10,"y": 20},
        {"id": 1,"x":20,"y": 10},
        {"id": 2,"x":30,"y": 70},
        {"id": 3,"x":40,"y": 80}  
       ]},    
    {"key":"comp2","values":[
        {"id": 0,"x":10,"y": 80},
        {"id": 1,"x":20,"y": 60},
        {"id": 2,"x":30,"y": 10},
        {"id": 3,"x":40,"y": 40}   
       ]} 
];

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([20, 300]);

svg.selectAll('text')
    .data(data)   
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.key; }) // so far so good
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.values[d.values.length - 1].x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.values[d.values.length - 1].y); })
    .attr("dy", ".35em");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg style="background-color: #eee; width: 100%; height: 300px;"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos, very elegant and works beautifully!